# can you call next js server actions as a reactQuery queryFn

Tags: next.js, next.js13, react-query, tanstackreact-query

Is it okay to replace an actual function with a server action when making a query or mutation with react query in next js 13-14

Answer (score 0):

yh i hv tried it and it works fine
the trick is instead of calling the queryFn directly, wrap it with an async function first

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).